# How do I import generated SDKs in golang?

Tags: go, openapi-generator, goimports

I've used [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) to generate multiple SDK separately and put it in the same parent dir:

```
sdks
--- bar-api
------ go.mod
--- foo-api
------ go.mod
```

I'd like to be able to import `bar-api` in my client code. Initially there's bar-api's `go.mod` was generated as:

```
module github.com/coolrepo/bar-api
go 1.13
```

but I couldn't fix the imports in my client code:

```
bar "github.com/cool-repo/bar-api"
```

so what I did was:

```
sdks
--- bar-api
------ go.mod
---go.mod
```

i.e., created `sdks/go.mod`:

```
module github.com/coolrepo

go 1.13
```

and manually edited bar-api's `go.mod` to:

```
module github.com/coolrepo/bar-api

require (
    ...
)

replace github.com/coolrepo => ./..

go 1.15
```

Is there a better way to fix it? This one seems to work but looks kinda hacky with this replace.

Comment: Do these really need to be separate modules? There's not much info on your use case, but it seems very common for folks to create submodules when all they really need is a package in the same module.

Comment: Well, this openapi-generator takes API's yaml and outputs a module (with a generated `go.mod`) and I don't really want to merge all API's yamls into a combined yaml if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The “better way to fix it” is to put all of the generated Go packages inside a single module, instead of splitting up the repo into multiple modules.

1. `rm bar-api/go.mod`
2. `go mod tidy`

You only really need to split a repo into separate modules if you need to be able to tag a release for one set of packages independently from another set of packages in the same repo. For generated service APIs, that probably isn't worth the development overhead of juggling versions for multiple modules.

Comment: hm since this openapi-generator takes API's yaml and outputs a module and I don't really want to merge all API's yamls into a combined yaml if that makes sense, would you suggest running `rm {api}/go.mod` as a separate hack / action? But it looks like a similar suggestion to what I've received in the comment section and I'm not sure I wanna do that.

Comment: From https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/4773, it looks like you may be able to use a `.openapi-generator-ignore` file to request that it skip those files.

Comment: interesting, that sounds like a plan, and how will I be able to import those packages then separately by the client code?

Comment: A module may contain more than one package, so you have the client code `require github.com/coolrepo vX.Y.Z` in their `go.mod` file, and then they can `import github.com/coolrepo/bar-api` in their `.go` source files to load the package found in that module.

Comment: Interesting, so essentially you're saying I should remove all coolrepo/{api}/go.mod files and have only `go.mod` as a repo root level (coolrepo/go.mod) and then I'll be able to imoport apis using e.g. `import github.com/coolrepo/bar-api`. How does this `coolrepo/go.mod` should look like?

Comment: figured, should be just module `github.com/coolrepo`, problem solved indeed, will add an answer in a bit